# Does Romania put visa refusal stamps?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, passport-stamps, romania

I had applied for Romanian visa but got rejected. I have this stamp in my passport. Is this a rejection stamp? What does this mean? Or do they do this on all applications?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This stamp means that you applied for a visa.

Typically you would only see this stamp if you asked for your passport to be returned while the consulate processed your application. They would then ask you to return the passport to affix the visa after approval.

If your visa was approved, then it would be placed on the same page and would completely cover the stamp.

Because you didn't receive a visa, the stamp is visible, and it is possible to infer that your visa application was refused.

Comment: "it is possible to infer that your visa application was refused" probably depends on the timing.  A couple weeks after the application, an impartial observer might be unable to conclude whether the application failed or still is being processed.  Not many people looking at passports are impartial though, they may assume the worst possibility.

Comment: @BenVoigt I would think that someone who applied for the visa in March 2018 probably isn't going to get it by now.